# Linker option / command to show cause of 'undefined reference to vtable for ...' error

Tags: g++

I recently ran into a problem linking one of my c++ projects. I was missing a virtual method's implementation, and g++ gave me a pretty unhelpful error message. All it said was 'undefined reference to vtable for [class]'.

I ended up finding the missing method by running 'nm -C [so file] | grep [class name]' and comparing the methods to the header, but I can see this being difficult for non-trivial classes.

Is there a linker option or utility that will do this automatically? (for my Makefile ideally)

Comment: Some compilers emit vtable in every translation unit, some compilers emit the vtable in the same translation unit as the first non-inlined virtual function.  If you've declared a virtual function, but have not defined it anywhere (or have defined it in a source file that isn't part of your project), then the vtable will be undefined.

Comment: Using inheritance in a different compiled file is not a good idea. Compile the whole source files at once. Always use C functions across diffrrent abi.